# Change value of dictionary within array in Swift 2

Tags: swift, nsarray, swift2, nsdictionary

I'm trying to change a value of a dictionary that is within an array. I made a small prototype in PlayGround:

```
var arr = [NSDictionary]()
arr.append(["name":"blue","view":"<object id=\"6787\">","visible":"true","locked":"false"])
arr.append(["name":"yellow","view":"<object id=\"345\">","visible":"true","locked":"false"])
arr.append(["name":"green","view":"<object id=\"123\">","visible":"false","locked":"true"])

//test remove
arr.removeAtIndex(2)

arr.count

//test edit
let nameChange = arr[1]
nameChange.setValue("black", forKey: "name")

arr[1]
```

But an error occurred, and I can not solve:
[image]

**Some can help me?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you created your dictionary as `NSDictionary` - the values can't change once they are set. But you still want to change them using `setValue()` and thats why you have the error. The fix is easy, change it to `NSMutableDictionary`. **BUT**. You shouldn't use Objective-C API, when you have Swift API. Thats why you should use Swift's `Dictionary`. How? e.g.

```
var arr = [[String:String]]()
arr.append(["name":"blue","view":"<object id=\"6787\">","visible":"true","locked":"false"])
arr.append(["name":"yellow","view":"<object id=\"345\">","visible":"true","locked":"false"])
arr.append(["name":"green","view":"<object id=\"123\">","visible":"false","locked":"true"])

//test remove
arr.removeAtIndex(2)

arr.count

//test edit
var nameChange = arr[1]
nameChange["name"] = "black"
```

Answer (score -1):

Finally Got Some Code,

```
let DuplicateArray: NSArray = array
let DuplicateMutableArray: NSMutableArray = []
DuplicateMutableArray.addObjectsFromArray(DuplicateArray as [AnyObject])
var dic = (DuplicateMutableArray[0] as! [NSObject : AnyObject])
dic["is_married"] = "false"
DuplicateMutableArray[self.SelectedIndexPath] = dic
array = []
array = (DuplicateMutableArray.copy() as? NSArray)!
```

//Output Will Be Like

```
array =  [
  {
    "name": "Kavin",
    "Age": 25,
    "is_married": "false"
  },
  {
    "name": "Kumar",
    "Age": 25,
    "is_married": "false"
  }
```

]